# Git rebase out an unwanted file change?

Tags: git

When I created a working branch on git, i did so on the incorrect one (which had some changes on which i did not want). Trouble is i didnt notice this mistake until i'd finished work on the branch.

I then did a rebase onto the master branch and a conflict raised with this file. I edited the conflict how i though it should have been resolved and continued the rebase.

Is there a way to remove the file from this branch, then have another rebase to master sort it out (the commit with that file's changes in it will be in master branch now)?

(ending up like if i hadn't created my changes over the top of that file commit at the start)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go back with a `git rebase --interactive`, and fix up the offending commit(s). Just be careful, it is easy to get mixed up. Keep a branch with the original around just in case, perhaps even work in a copy (clone) of the repository, or set up a mock one for fooling around. When you are done, you can push the result.

Be careful, messing with *published* history will confuse the heck out of anyone who got your branches in the meantime.